# Does Entity Framework need to be installed for all projects in a solution?

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have a VS2013 solution that contains two projects. The first project is my Entity Framework Model and the second project contains the Windows Form I want to use the EF models in.

Does the Entity Framework need to be installed in the Windows Form project if it is making use  of the objects from the Entity Framework Model project? Is it enough just to reference the Entity Framework project from within the Windows Form project?

I am using Entity Framework 6 in Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reference the Entity Framework because you are using your models that need the entity framework to work...

Anyway you can try to remove the Entity Framework reference from your Windows Form project and see if it works... If it compile then everything is fine, otherwise you will have to add the reference again.